# No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]

Tags: java, jsf-2, cdi

I wanted to inject the default Java logger. However, Eclipse underlines it and states "No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]"

If I deploy anyway, the following exception is thrown. Why does it fail to inject Java Logger? Same for the EntityManager, but not for my own UserRepository Bean.

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field]
```

code:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.terry.webapp.data.UserRepository;
import com.terry.webapp.model.usermgmt.User;


// The @Stateless annotation eliminates the need for manual transaction demarcation
@Stateless
public class LoginService {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private UserRepository repository;

    public User login(User user) {
        log.info("login " + user.getUsername());

        User rUser = repository.findByCredentials(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return rUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To inject a logger you need a producer method which gives a `Logger` which you can Inject.

```
  import java.util.logging.Logger;   

  import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;   
  import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;   

  public class LoggerProduer {   

    @Produces   
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {   
      return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass()   
          .getName());   
    }   
  }
```

And `EntityManager` needs to be injected using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="pscontext")` because it's created using data in your `persistence.xml`, so your `EntityManager` has to be

```
   @PersistenceContex(unitName="pscontext")
   private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: You can also use: @ Produces  @ PersistenceContex(unitName="pscontext")
EntityManager em; if you want to @ Inject the EntityManager.

Comment: I just don't understand when you need to create your own Producer and when it applicable to simple user @Inject. What are the prerequisites for this?

Comment: Check out this post you will understand more about Producer methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534728/please-explain-the-produces-annotation-in-cdi. Like @AVolpe..mentioned If you use `producer method ` to create `EntityManager` and `Inject` in other classes you don't need to look for all the places to change name of the `@ PersistenceContext` when you change name in the `persistence.xml`

Comment: I have the same problem, and the only way to make this work is changing the EJB to Stateful, why is that? I need to make it work with Stateless EJBs.