# Can a CDI Bean's method return a managed Bean it created?

Tags: java, cdi

i have the following setup:

```
@Applicationscoped
@Transactional(txtype.Requires_new)
Public class querybean {

    @Inject ExternalSysrltem externalSystemProxy;

    Public Handle gethandleByKey(String key) {
        return new Handle(/*do external Systems Query, returns an ExternalHandle Object*/)
    }

    Public static class Handle {
        ExternalHandle eh;
        /*protected so that User of class cannot Instantiate it otherwise that by getHandleByKey()*/
        Protected Handle(ExternalHandle arg) {
            This.eh = arg;
        }

        Public String getHandleInfo() {
            Return This.eh.getName() + "/" + this.eh.getState()..;
            /*generally wrap the ExternallHandle with businesslogic to hide direct access to the complex ExternalService's Interface*/
        }
    }
}
```

Can I get `Handle` to be a Managed Bean that can be annotated with @Transactional and still create it in the `getHandleByKey` Method at Runtime by querying the external System?

Comment: You could use [`@Produces`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534728/please-explain-the-produces-annotation-in-cdi).

Answer (score 1):

A static inner class can be a bean according the the [spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#what_classes_are_beans).
In your example it is not a bean due to its constructor.
As said in comments you could use a producer, but a produced bean can't be intercepted (with `@Transaction` here)

If you want to keep your pattern, you'll have to create a very complex extension since it should work at low level to ensure interceptor will be activated.

I suggest that you go for something simpler by deporting your `ExternalHandle` resolution in `Handle` Bean, allowing you to use a `String` to construct it.

First create a qualifier with a non binding member to transmit information to your constructor.

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface Keyed {

    @Nonbinding
    String key();
}
```

Then create a literal for your annotation to allow creation of an annotation instance with a given `key` value.

```
public class KeyedLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Keyed> implements Keyed {

    private final String key;

    public KeyedLiteral(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Using [programmatic](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#programmatic_lookup) lookup and [InjectionPoint](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injection_point) to transmit your key value.  Your code will be like:

```
@Applicationscoped
@Transactional(txtype.Requires_new)
Public class querybean {
    @Inject
    @Any
    Instance<Handle> handles;

    Public Handle gethandleByKey(String key) {
        return instances.select(new KeyedLiteral(key)).get()
    }

    @Dependent
    @Transactional
    @Keyed("") //enforce the presence of the annotation for the constructor
    Public static class Handle {

        ExternalHandle eh;

        // needed to make the bean proxyable (mandatory for the interceptor bound)) 
        Protected Handle() {}

        @Inject
        Protected Handle(InjectionPoint ip, ExternalSysrltem externalSystem) {
            String key=ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Keyed.class).key();
            eh = /*do external Systems Query, returns an ExternalHandle Object from key and externalSystem*/
        }

        Public String getHandleInfo() {
            Return This.eh.getName() + "/" + this.eh.getState()..;
            /*generally wrap the ExternallHandle with businesslogic to hide direct access to the complex ExternalService's Interface*/
        }
    }
}
```